# Duplicate object including physics settings in python for Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, cloth-simulation

I can duplicate an object and its materials in python for Blender 2.8; so far so good
How do I copy its physics, say Cloth, settings?

Code so far, manually copying the settings I need:

````
balloon=bpy.data.objects['Balloon']

dup= bpy.data.objects.new(balloon.name, balloon.data.copy())
dup.active_material= balloon.active_material.copy()

bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(dup)    

# Copy cloth modifier
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = dup
dup.select_set(True)  
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')

# Copy cloth settings
dup.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.use_pressure = True
dup.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.uniform_pressure_force = 2

```
````

Comment: Hi. What code have you got so far and where *specifically* are you getting stuck?

Comment: Added a code fragment, where I am manually adding a new modifier, setting its properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to duplicate an object in 2.8 via the Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135597/how-to-duplicate-an-object-in-2-8-via-the-python-api)