# Blender scripting scalling down the copy of object

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to scale down a copy that would be 75% smaller. However, when I execute my code, the copy becomes not smaller but opposite, bigger.

```
import bpy

# reads selected object data
objektas = bpy.context.object

# for loop index
i = 0

# vertices data
v = objektas.data.vertices

if objektas.type == 'MESH':
    for i in range(len(v)):
        for v in objektas.data.vertices:
            v.co += (0.75 * v.normal)
            Cube = bpy.data.objects.new('Cube', objektas.data)
bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects.link(Cube)
```

Comment: Maybe inverted normals ?

Comment: Well I haven't done it yet, but I'll make 8 total copies of the bigger cube and then I'll move them to each vertice of original cube.

Comment: you are manipulating the original object not the copy. whatever, in addition to mistaken `+` sign in `v.co += (0.75 * v.normal)` you should consider that normal vectors are unit vectors. you should use `v.co *= 0.75` instead

Comment: Q code scales the shared (linked) mesh of both the original and copy.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135608/15543   Any reason not to use object scale?  eg `cube = context.object.copy()`  then `cube.scale *= 0.75`