# Efficiently duplicate objects while preserving all relative relationships?

Tags: python

`bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` preserves the relative relationships between duplicated objects— Properties originally set to any of the original objects in parenting, modifiers, constraints, and drivers get set to their corresponding duplicated objects.

What would be the most efficient way to replicate this behaviour with low-level calls? Traversing the objects' hierarchies to find and replace all constraint, modifier, and driver fields that refer to the original objects would surely nullify much of the performance gain from using low-level calls in the first place.

Comment: Related or dupe: [How to duplicate an object in 2.8 via the Python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135597/how-to-duplicate-an-object-in-2-8-via-the-python-api)

Comment: @brockmann Different question, I think. That's about keeping the original data, unmodified, on a single object. It doesn't seem to say anything about about retargeting/preserving relative relationships across multiple objects, much less doing so efficiently.